# imagejpeg(); not generating image on host server , working fine on localhost

Tags: php, image, image-processing, jpeg

I have this code which is supposed to generate a captcha image of random number , it's working fine on localhost but not on my hosting, Can anyone help please? Can someone tell me where am i going wrong ?

```
         <?php
 session_start();
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

 $text= $_SESSION['secure'];

 $font_size =30;
 $image_width= 110;
 $image_height=40;

 $image=imagecreate($image_width,$image_height);
 imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
 $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);


 for($x=1; $x<=30; $x++){
$x1 = rand(1,100);
$x2 = rand(1,100);
$y1 = rand(1,100);
$y2 = rand(1,100);
 imageline($image, $x1, $x2, $y1, $y2, $text_color);
}

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'font.ttf', $text);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

And then i include the file that contains the above code in a new html file where i have my form and calling the image like this :

```
 <img src="generate.php"/>
```

Comment: Did you copy your font `font.ttf` in the same folder as the script ?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your server has the gd library installed? Use phpinfo() to check.

Comment: Use `wget` or `curl` to download the complete `generate.php` image url. Inspect headers and resulting binary data. Are there error messages perhaps? (Else enable error_reporting, and check the log.)

Comment: I figured out the issue , the font file i coded in my file was named as font.ttf whereas the original font file was font.TTF

That solved the issue! 
Thanks David Belanger!

Comment: What is the problem?  Is it creating a broken image?  Try comment out the the "header('Content-type: image/jpeg');" line and browse directly to generate.php Can you see any errors then?

Comment: @user1216752 My pleasure. Also, thanks to the moderator who banned my "answer" who was right even if it was a "comment" ... it wasn't a comment itself but an answer. Get your fact straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your script with string `hello` and it works

[image: image generated]

Am very sure the issue is that `PHP` can not located the font .. try using full system path

Try

```
$font = dirname ( __FILE__ ) . "/verdana.ttf" ;
if(!is_file($font))
{
    die("Missing Font");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have NO leading spaces or newlines in your script.  Any text outputted before attempting to display an image will cause it to fail.